# How to change Javafx default app image/icon/thumb

Tags: java, javafx

I developed a javafx application. I want to change the java default icon of .jar file. I tried  this 
   primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);

but this only make change the left top corner icon when running the app not the external view image.

screenshot below:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoShA.png
  I want to change this icon actually.

Answer (score 2):

All Jar files have the same icon and it depends on the OS to show an icon on a file depending on the file type.

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
```

The above line will only get executed when a JVM is created for the application, so it doesn't make sense to depend on this particular piece code to display an icon :)

If you want to change the file icon, you will have to wrap the executable jar file to create a new native executable file (which depends on the OS). For example - EXE for windows. This new file will contain the image file to be displayed and the jar to be executed.

You can try using [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) for creating a wrapper file.

Comment: Or, he can use [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/), which comes with every JRE, and like all Java technologies, is highly stable and well documented.